# Workflow: Trigger If Item deleted work around

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, item-deleted

So I'm looking into triggering a workflow on delete and have stumbled upon something I can't get my head around.
Now I know there isn't an OOTB solution to trigger a workflow on delete. However as custom code is a no go for this project I was determined to find some work around. I created a workflow with the logic:
wait for Current Item:ID to not equal Current Item:ID
then send email to user
As expected nothing happens however I than began looking at setting up the standard alerts in the list and set these up to alert when items are deleted.
I forgot to stop the workflow I created from running when item is modified and did some testing with the OOTB alerts on deleting and my workflow emails were being sent alongside the standard alerts but when I removed the alerts these emails wouldn't come through either. Can anyone explain what's happening here? How are the standard alerts triggering the emails in the workflow?
EDIT: I'm using sharepoint 2013 on premise